# Installing Drupal on Azure PaaS with SQL Backend

Tags: php, azure, drupal, drupal-7

Trying to install Drupal with SQL Azure backend and getting error below:

[image: Error from Drupal]

PDO is enabled:

[image: PHPInfo() result]

If I comment out line 124 in database.inc the installation proceeds and I see some tables being created in MS SQL. However, it breaks at some point with:

> Cannot convert '0' to int SQL Driver error

Which I assume is caused by not having setting above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use the template `Acquia Drupal 7 on SQL` from Azure Marketplace to create Drupal app with Azure SQL.

1. In Azure **Marketplace** blade, search for **Drupal**, and then click **Acquia Drupal 7 on SQL**.

[image]

2. Configure Azure App Service Settings for your New Web App.

[image]

3. When the web app creation is finished, you can launch and manage your Drupal web app in the browser.